# How to catch function keys (F3, F4...) value in a variable into a script shell?

Tags: bash, dd, function-keys

I'm searching for a way to catch the value of function keys in a variable, when a user press a function key.
I have tried with `dd` command but only the letters or numbers keys are trapped: dd command doesn't work why the function keys.

Here are several tests lines I have tried, but the variable always return nothing with function keys :

```
selection=`dd if=/dev/tty bs=2 count=2 2>/dev/null`
selection=$(dd bs=2 count=2 2>/dev/null)
selection=`dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null`
selection=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)
selection=`head -c1`
selection=$(head -c1)
```

For example

- when I push F3 key, value `^[[13~` appears on the screen but when doing `echo selection=$selection`, my variable "selection" remains empty (selection=)
- when I push d key, value d appears on the screen and when doing echo selection=$selection, my variable "selection" equal (selection=d)

Why doesn't it work with function keys (F3...)?

Comment: Might try the Unix stack exchange.

Comment: is it resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

- Read code of keys
  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and press a key. <kbd>F1</kbd> for example
  And read the output. <kbd>F1</kbd> gives `^[OP`
  Note that `^[` is for <kbd>Escape</kbd> that you will write in a script as `\e`
- Or get all codes of functions keys
  `for x in {1..24}; do echo -n "F$x "; tput kf$x | cat -A; echo; done`
  Assuming <kbd>F13</kbd> is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Handle keys in script
  With bash functions like `while`, `read`, `case / esac`

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

ReadKey() {
  if read -sN1 KEY; then
    while read -sN1 -t 0.001 ; do
      KEY+="${REPLY}"
    done
  fi
}

while ReadKey; do
  case "${KEY}" in
    $'\eOP')   echo 'F1';;
    $'\e[24~') echo 'F12';;
    *) echo    "Keys pressed: ${KEY}";;
  esac
done
```